# Write a function that, given a prop name as argument, returns an object prop correctly

Tags: typescript

I have a function to write DB queries. Here is an oversimplified example:

```js
// DB Types
type UserData = {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  email: string
}

type UserSettings = {
  id: string,
  language: string,
  country: string
}

type Tables = {
  user: 'user'
  userSettings: 'userSettings'
}


const dbQueries = {
  user: {
    create: (args: {data: UserData}) => {/* ...queryDB */ },
    read: (userId: string) => {/* ...queryDB */ }
    //... other CRUD queries
  },
  userSettings: {
    create: (args: {data: UserSettings}) => {/* ...queryDB */ },
    read: (userSettingId: string) => {/* ...queryDB */ }
    //... other CRUD queries
  }
}

type AllowedTables = keyof Tables

// Here I want to wrap all the queries to modify some of them
// and return all the queries for a specific entity (e.g. all
// the queries for 'userSettings')
const getModifiedQueriesForEntity = <
  EntityName extends AllowedTables,
>(entityName: EntityName) => {
  const queries = dbQueries[entityName];

  // I want to wrap the original `create` query to do two things:
  // 1. avoid having to wrap the entity into 'data'
  // 2. abstract away the ID generation, so that the caller doesn't have
  //    to worry about it.
  const create = (args: Parameters<typeof queries.create>[0]['data']) => {
    const id: string = getRandomId(); // returns a string
    return queries.create({data: {...args, id}});
  }

  // I leave the other queries untouched
  return {
    ...queries,
    create
  }
}
```

But at the line     `return queries.create({data: {...args, id}});` I get the following ts error:

```
Type '{ id: any; name: string; email: string; } | { id: any; language: string; country: string; }' is not assignable to type 'UserData & UserSettings'.
  Type '{ id: any; name: string; email: string; }' is not assignable to type 'UserData & UserSettings'.
    Type '{ id: any; name: string; email: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'UserSettings': language, countryts(2322)
```

and also calling the function doesn't return the correct signatures:

```js
const {create: createUser} = getModifiedQueriesForEntity('user');

// here intellisense suggests __all__ properties of User and UserSettings **combined**
createUser({
  country, // from UserSettings
  name // from User
})
```

I understand that typescript is trying to find only things that work for both User and UserSetting types, but I want it to discern the two based on the `entityName`.

Comment: Does `getRandomId()` return a type string?

Comment: yes @BrendanOtherwhyz. I will edit the question to make it more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to detect types at runtime in typescript so you have to be quite deliberate and explicit with how you use them. It is possible to infer types in run time but you need to use `type predicates`. That's probably overkill here.

The main issue is that if you're returning an object from a function, and itself contains a function which can have different argument types depending on the input. Typescript has no idea how to handle this except for combining the argument types together. Hence why you need to separate them. So in answer to the question in the title, it's not possible, as far as I'm aware.

This is how I would implement your code above.

```
// DB Types
type UserData = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    email: string
}

type UserSettings = {
    id: string,
    language: string,
    country: string
}

type Tables = {
    user: 'user'
    userSettings: 'userSettings'
}

// create function arguments accept data with both types (UserData and UserSettings)
const dbQueries = {
    user: {
        create: (args: { data: UserData }) => {/* ...queryDB */ },
        read: (userId: string) => {/* ...queryDB */ }
        //... other CRUD queries
    },
    userSettings: {
        create: (args: { data: UserSettings }) => {/* ...queryDB */ },
        read: (userSettingId: string) => {/* ...queryDB */ }
        //... other CRUD queries
    }
}

enum AllowedTables {
    user = 'user',
    userSettings = 'userSettings'
}

function getRandomId(): string {
    return '1';
}

var createUser;
let entityName = AllowedTables.user;
if (entityName == AllowedTables.user) {
    createUser = {
        ...dbQueries.user,
    }
    createUser.create = (args: { data: UserData }) => {
        const id = getRandomId();
        const data = { ...args };
        data.data.id = id;
        return dbQueries.user.create(data)
    }
    createUser.create({
        data: {
            id: 'foo',
            name: 'bar',
            email: 'baz'
        }
    })
} else if (entityName == AllowedTables.userSettings) {
    createUser = {
        ...dbQueries.userSettings
    }
    createUser.create = (args: { data: UserSettings }) => {
        const id = getRandomId();
        const data = { ...args }
        data.data.id = id;
        return dbQueries.userSettings.create(data)
    }
    createUser.create({
        data: {
            id: 'foo',
            language: 'bar',
            country: 'baz'
        }
    })
}
```

I hope this helps